# How to create QR code in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, qr-code

I want to generate QR code for my Laravel 5.2 application. I have searched and found a library for that. Its **[Simple qr-code.](https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode)**

I have installed it. and configure Service provider file perfectly (`config/app.php`).

```
<div class="visible-print text-center">
    {{ QrCode::size(1)->generate(Request::url()) }}
    <p>Scan me to return to the original page.</p>
</div>
```

I see some code in `<div class="visible-print text-center"> </div>`. **[Here](https://prnt.sc/gq8iqd)** is the `blade` view. My question is how can print view of qr code? It should be something like this:

[image]

Or is there any good laravel library to generate QR code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The QR code is currently being escaped. If you don't want it to be escaped, use:

```
{!! QrCode::size(1)->generate(Request::url()) !!}
```